# Is it possible to have cmake build file (CMakeLists.txt) not in root in CLion

Tags: cmake, clion

Is it possible to have cmake build file (CMakeLists.txt) not in root directory in CLion?

I am currently working on project where cmake build file is not in not in the root directory of a CLion project (in out/Debug directory). I want CLion to open root of this project, and use cmake from out/Debug.

Is is possible?
EXAMPLE:

```
|- main.cpp
|- classs.cpp
|- class.h
|- build1
   |- CMakeLists.txt
|- build2
   |- CMakeLists.txt
```

This is a little bit unusual, but think of situation when cmake file is generated.

Also, it can be possible when two projects want to have separate make files and common sources.

Comment: "not in root in CLion" you mean, "not in the root directory of a CLion project", right? Then I doubt it.

Comment: yes, thanks, I changes the description a little bit

Comment: The question is really unclear, sorry. Please show your directory structure.

Comment: Added more clerification

Answer (score 8):

Just to clarify, CLION has solution for it.

Please do the following:

```
 use 'Welcome Screen | Open Project', point to CMakeLists.txt
 use 'Tools | CMake | Change Project Root', and point to the actual project's root.
```

Comment: This worked for me on CLion 1.2.1. I couldn't find any other workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, I created a bug for that

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-2943

you can vote it you think it is useful

Comment: From CMake's perspective, it does not make sense to have a project root directory, that does not contain a CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: oh really? I dont think so. You can take a look at Chromium, for example, where CMakeFIles are generated from gyp files. They have them in ./out/Debug and ./out/Release folders.

Comment: Interesting. I was not aware that you can generate CMake files from gyp. I thought gyp generates Ninja files.

Comment: gyp generates cmake, ninja and more)

Comment: Here are types you can generate with gyp https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp.git/+/master/pylib/gyp/generator/